# Can't connect to wifi hotspot on 18.04 Ubuntu, Realtek [10ec:d723]

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04. All things are working properly, but I cannot connect to my mobile Hotspot with it.

I have noticed that there is no additional  driver for it, though I can connect to internet via USB cable with my phone. Please help me out with this problem.

[image: screenshot with hardware details]

Comment: are you trying to share your mobile internet with Ubuntu system? what is the output of `nmcli device wifi list` ??

Comment: no, actually my problem is i don't see any Wifi lists .After doing nmcli device wifi list,it is showing me nothing

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).